# How to know which utility installed a particular utility?

Tags: dependencies

While working, I saw today that both `texlive-base` and `texlive-latex-base` were installed on my system but I did not explicitly install them and no one else uses my computer.

So, I guess both these packages got installed while fulfilling dependencies of some other package I might have installed earlier.

I want to find out which packages in my system might have installed these 2 packages.

OR which packages already installed on my system need these 2 packages to be installed.

How do I do that?

I am using `apt-get`

---

Update

```
$ aptitude why texlive-base
i   wifitap            Depends    python-pyx                     
i A python-pyx         Recommends texlive-latex-base             
i A texlive-latex-base Depends    texlive-base (>= 2017.20170628)

$ aptitude why texlive-latex-base
i   wifitap    Depends    python-pyx        
i A python-pyx Recommends texlive-latex-base
```

Comment: which port or package system are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`aptitude` can tell you — install it if you don’t have it already, then run

```
aptitude why texlive-base
```

to see the strongest dependency causing `texlive-base` to be installed.

```
aptitude why texlive-latex-base
```

will do the same for `texlive-latex-base`.

You can add `-v` to see all the dependencies leading to `texlive-base` on your system:

```
aptitude why -v texlive-base
```

You can also run `aptitude` and use its UI to explore packages depending on `texlive-base`.

In your specific case, the output means that `wifitap` was installed explicitly, which caused `python-pyx`, `texlive-latex-base` and `texlive-base` to be installed automatically (hence the `A`). Recommended packages are installed by default; if you don’t want that to happen, set the `APT::Install-Recommends` option to `"false"` in `/etc/apt/apt.conf`:

```
APT::Install-Recommends "false";
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I did just that, but I do not understand `A` in the output, I have updated it in question, could you please let me know.. And also the output says, `wifitap` depends on `python-pyx` but `python-pyx` only recommends `texlive-latex-base` then why was `texlive-latex-base` installed in the first place when it does not depend (is just recommended, I guess recommended shouldn't have been installed by default)

Comment: OK, see my update.